# Writing unicode symbols to files (as opposed to unicode code)

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I'm new to python and unicode is starting to give me headaches.

Currently I write to file like this:

```
my_string = "马/馬"
f = codecs.open(local_filepath, encoding='utf-8', mode='w+')
f.write(my_string)
f.close()
```

And when I open file with i.e. Gedit, I can see something like this:

```
\u9a6c/\u99ac\tm\u01ce
```

While I'd like to see exactly what I've written:

```
马/馬
```

I've tried a few different variations, like writing my_string.decode() or my_string.encode('utf-8') instead of just my_string, I know those two methods are the opposites but I was not sure which one I needed. Neither worked anyway.

If I manually write these symbols to text file, then with python read the file, re-write what I've just read back to the same file and save, symbols get turned to the code \u9a6c. Not sure if this is importat, figured I'd just mention it to help identify the problem.

**Edit**: the strings came from SQL Alchemy objects **repr** method, which turned out to be where the problem lied. I didn't mention it because it just didn't occur to me it can be related to the problem somehow. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: That's **Gedit** showing you those escapes then, because Python certainly isn't writing those. Not that your code produces valid output, as `my_string` is *not a Unicode string*. It is a bytestring and what bytes are contained is dependent on your source encoding.

Comment: Can you give us an actual *reproducable sample*. If you run your code in the interpreter you'll either get a source codec warning (no codec declared), or a UnicodeDecodeError exception as the bytes are decoded from ASCII before the `codecs.open()` file object can encode them to UTF-8.

Comment: Gedit is just an example, I've tried different text editors. I've also tried opening it in a different editor, pasting in Chinese symbols, opening in Gedit, and then I do see symbols. So it's definitely Python that writes Chinese in such way. Probably because I am doing something wrong.

Comment: It's worth noting `codecs.open()` works just like `open()`, so you can [use a context manager](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4), which is more readable, and will stop bugs.

Comment: @Sejanus: this code is not writing those escapes. If `my_string` is *actually a unicode value*, then the bytes E9, A9, AC, 2F, E9, A6 and AC are written.

Comment: How can I check for sure if my_string is actually a unicode value? And why the provably wrong comment is already upvoted twice, and genuine question already voted for close? If you can't help don't hurt. Maybe someone else knows the answer from experience. Unicode in Python 2.7 is not an easy thing for beginners.

Comment: @Sejanus: Try your code you posted here in an interactive Python session. You'll get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`. If you replace `my_string = "马/馬"` with `my_string = u"马/馬"` you'll get a file that contains the byte sequence I described. Verify it by using `print repr(open(local_filepath, 'rb').read())`; you can post that output here if you like; it should print `'\xe9\xa9\xac/\xe9\xa6\xac'`.

Comment: @Sejanus: I'd love for you to show us code that proves my comment wrong, I'm trying to give you feedback on how you can do so.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters thank you I appreciate your help. What proves you wrong is that if I write the same symbols to the same file via different editor (not python) and open it in Gedit, Gedit shows them correctly. Hence it's not Gedit's fault period. I will try and determine if the string is actually unicode, that may be where the problem lies indeed

Comment: @Sejanus: no, what would prove me wrong is for you to show that the data written to the file is not `'\xe9\xa9\xac/\xe9\xa6\xac'`. But you'll have to show us code that actually works and reproduces the problem for you.

Comment: No. What I said already proves you wrong.

Comment: @Sejanus: `\u9a6c/\u99ac\tm\u01ce` would be written if you wrote *representations* or JSON escaped data to the file. I can reproduce your problem if I used `my_string = repr(u"马/馬")` for example.

Comment: yes the strings come from sql alchemy  __repr__ method (should be underscores) if that is what you meant by representations, I will update my question (I am very new to python like I said). Should I explicitly cast them to Unicode somehow to solve this?

Comment: `repr()` (and `__repr__`) on python 2.7 returns a string that makes a representation that escapes the Unicode characters with `\u`, it is not meant to be *user readable*, only *programmer readable*. Solution: **do not use `__repr__`**

Comment: @Sejanus: yes, you should definitely update your post to reflect this. That's what I meant by providing a way to reproduce your problem. You need to give us something that a) works, and b) you have tested yourself to reproduce the actual problem.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters  the problem was repr indeed, I fixed it. If you posted it as an answer I could formally accept it. Thanks a bunch for taking your time to reproduce the bug, it would have never occured to me to look for potential problems there! And, well, I hope now you can see it was not Gedit problem.

Comment: @Sejanus: Annti already stated this but I'll repeat it for clarity: you are writing debug information to your file, `repr()` is meant to produce information that a programmer can use to diagnose the code. For unicode strings it produces ASCII-save representations that can re-create the exact value in a new Python session.

Comment: Got it. From the examples I was learning from, I assumed repr is something similar to PHP's __toString() to cast object into string. I edited my code and got rid of it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it is now clear you are using either the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) or calling the [`object.__repr__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) directly.

Don't do that. You are writing *debugging information* to your file:

```
>>> my_string = u"马/馬"
>>> print repr(my_string)
u'\u9a6c/\u99ac'
```

The value produced is meant to be pastable back into a Python session so you can re-produce the exact same value, and as such it is ASCII-safe (so it can be used in Python 2 source code without encoding issues).

From the `repr()` documentation:

> For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to `eval()`, otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and address of the object.

Write the Unicode objects to your file directly instead, `codecs.open()` handles encoding to UTF-8 correctly if you do.